# Подключение скриптов в HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста. Что это за вид подключения и как поменять на обычный? Пытался все подключения поменять на `script src=""` и некоторые не работают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что это за вид подключения

В данном случае дополнительные скрипты подключаются JavaScript'ом при помощи библиотеки LABjs.

> Пытался все подключения поменять на script src="" и некоторые не
>   работают

Скорее всего, что-то не подгружается или не отрабатывает корректно. Возможно возникают блокировки. Но, чтобы сказать точно нужно, как минимум, смотреть вывод консоли.